# How to try ubuntu live image on acer iconia w4-820 Win 8.1 tablet?

Tags: windows-8, uefi, live-usb, acer, tablet

I have Acer iconia W4-820 windows 8.1 tablet which is an UEFI boot device. its secure boot is enabled. I dont know anything about UEFI hoe to play with it. I just want to try ubuntu desktop images on my Acer Iconia W4-820 device, I made a bootable pendrive when i connect it using OTG cable it dont load booting directly goes to hard disk boot of windows. I changed the boot device priority in UEFI. But nothing works.

Anyone tried booting ubuntu on Acer Iconia W4-820 tablet ? Please I need a help.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? [I have a similar issue.](http://superuser.com/questions/883915/cant-boot-a-64bit-windows-usb-from-a-tablet-originally-installed-with-32-bit-os)

Comment: No I didn't, Tablet is lock for windows OS

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried but you can enter the BIOS by holding the volume-up and power button (to turn on device). For me it didn't work the first few tries, I guess you either have to hold or release the volume button.
When you are in the BIOS screen you can change boot-order to USB but you can also disable secure-boot.
With both of these options set and a USB-OTG + bootable-USB-drive it should work I guess.

Comment: There's a lot of guessing in this 'answer' and the OP already stated that changing the boot-order doesn't work. Furthermore he clearly states that he has a UEFI boot loader and not BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable the "secure boot" setting in the UEFI. Also check if there is a setting for legacy support, if so enable it. It can be that those functions prevent the device from booting into another OS.